# Sed extract data from html table

Tags: html, extract, regex, sed

With sed I can extract data from an HTML file? For example like this:

```
<html>
...
<table>
<tr>
 <td>R1A</td><td>R1B</td>
 <td>R1C</td><td>R1D</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>R2X</td><td>R2Y</td>
 <td>R2W</td><td>R2Z</td>
</tr>
</table>
....
</html>
```

Extract this output:

```
R1A R1B R1C R1D
R2X R2Y R2W R2Z
```

In my text editor I use the following regular expression:

```
/<tr>.*?<td>(.*?)</td>.*?<td>(.*?)</td>.*?<td>(.*?)</td>.*?<td>(.*?)</td>.*?</tr>/s
```

Comment: This is not a *do my work for me site*. I could solve this **easily** but you haven't even bothered to make a polite question out of it.

Comment: This way madness lies: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: Politeness helps

Comment: @Nifle: I understand. I was too direct. Sorry.

Comment: No need to all pile onto a new user.  Politeness from old users helps, too.

Answer (score 1):

Not a sed solution but an XSLT one

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >
<xsl:output method="text" />

  <xsl:template match="//table/tr">
     <xsl:value-of select="descendant::td[1]"/>
     <xsl:text>  </xsl:text>
     <xsl:value-of select="descendant::td[2]"/>
     <xsl:text>  </xsl:text>
     <xsl:value-of select="descendant::td[3]"/>
     <xsl:text>  </xsl:text>
     <xsl:value-of select="descendant::td[4]"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: But if HTML is malformed, this solution works?